# Applet JAR loading fails, since the http request doesn't include a basic auth header

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

It's a farily simple setup. A .jar is hosted on a site which is protected by basic auth. I try to load the jar with an object tag - which works perfectly when tested without authentication.

When the .jar is requested from the server, the basic auth header isn't included in the request. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the JVM itself is making the HTTP request and not using the browser's HTTP stack to do so.

There's at least one other question here at SO asking the same question but instead of "the basic auth header" being missing, it's "the user's cookies".

Only Sun could really fix that.